# Overwrite register keyword

Tags: c++, c

Having in mind that `register` is a keyword and that we could use to name functions/methods (i really miss it), we can't do that. But I wonder, is it dangerous to overwrite that keyword?

```
#define register ...
```

Will be any kind of side effects?

Comment: Just do it after all includes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++ says, in `17.6.4.3.1[macro.names]/2`

> A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords

although this falls under

> This section describes restrictions on C++ programs that use the facilities of the C++ standard library

C says, in `7.1.2/4`

> The program shall not have any macros with names lexically identical
>   to keywords currently defined prior to the inclusion of the header or
>   when any macro defined in the header is expanded

so, in C, you could put that after all `#include`s  (Edit: as pointed out in comments, even in C, using a macro that comes from a standard library header after your `#define` would be formally undefined, since it might be using that keyword)

Comment: Note that in the overview for the section ([constraints.overview]), there's *This section describes restrictions on C++ programs that use the facilities of the C++ standard library.* I wouldn't recommend doing this even without using the standard library, but it is at least legal then.

Comment: @chris indeed, thanks for pointing it out (although 'using the facilities' looks like a stronger restriction than what C has)

Comment: It's allowed after all `#include`s **only if** you refrain from using any macros defined in the included headers. For example, if you so much as use `NULL`, you have violated this rule.

Comment: For that reason and the answer of @Walter (which I consider a really good cause for not doing that), I will put this as solved. - But as I said before, such a shame, a really good name and we can't use. I made a research about that keyword and I haven't see reasons for using it (I mean, good), and that is why I feel like a shame that we can't use it just because it's defined already. But thank you guys.

Comment: @MrAlmighty, in C++ `register` is basically useless. In C it isn't. Here it specifies that you don't have the right to take the address of such a variable. This can be interesting to ensure some optimizations, in particular to inhibit any aliasing for that variable.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it were not prohibited by the spec, it will still break things if you do it.

The following source:

```
#define foo register int a;

#define register static

int main()
{
    foo
    return 0;
}
```

produces this when run through the MSVC compiler with the /P switch

```
#line 1 "test.cpp"

int main()
{
    static int a;
    return 0;
}
```

What this means is that even though your #define follows any #defines in headers that might include the word "register" in their expansions, due to the way C/C++ macro expansions happen, you will break those macros.

Answer (score 1):

Even it it would be allowed and/or work, **don't do that**. It makes not just your program unreadable, because `register` will be confused (and is extremely poor coding style), but all programs that `#include` your header file!

Rather use a related name ('Register' or similar).

**Avoid macros** as much as possible. In particular such stupid macros as `MAX` or `MIN` (which are defined in some library headers). They confuse everybody and can cause serious headache, because the compiler doesn't know about them, such that your inadvertent use of `MAX` as an identifier causes confusing compiler messages.

Comment: That is true, but it's a shame that `register` is a keyword, such a good name to functions/methods.

Comment: @MrAlmighty: So are `delete` and `new` -- also a bad idea (as your post is tagged `C++`).

Comment: @Jongware - I don't see `delete` and `new` as bad ideas, not because of the name, but because of the usage. Every language that I used that supports OO uses those keywords to instantiate an object.